# Powershell file extension match .*

Tags: powershell, file-extension

I need to match the extension to ".*" to return all files in a given source folder that have the LastWriteTime of $lwt as shown in code. The user can either provide a specific extension like ".csv" but one is not provided then the script will simply search all files. But i can't match the extension with ".*" to return all files.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$source,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$destination,
[string]$exten=".*",
[int]$olderthandays = 30
)
$lwt = (get-date).AddDays(-$olderthandays)

if(!(Test-Path $source)){
    Write-Output "Source directory does not exist."
    exit
}

if(!(Test-Path $destination)){
    Write-Output "Source directory does not exist."
    exit
}

if($olderthandays -lt 0){
    Write-Output "You can't provide a negative number of days. If you want everything deleted simply provide 0 for number of days."
    exit
}

if(!$exten.StartsWith(".")){
    $exten = "."+$exten
    $exten
}


try{
    Get-ChildItem $source -ErrorAction Stop | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $lwt -AND $_.Extension -eq $exten} | foreach {
        Write-Output $_.FullName 
       # Move-item $_.FullName $destination -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
catch{
    Write-Output "Something went wrong while moving items. Aborted operation."
}
```

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: What does "matching the extension to '.*'" mean? So, like, a filename of "/Users/foo/Documents/bar.*" would match? Or something else, because ".*" is very meaningful in regex.

Comment: I mean to say any extension like so be it .csv, .pdf or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Extension` of a file will never be `.*`.

You could try:

```
$exten = "*.$exten"
Get-ChildItem $source -ErrorAction Stop -Filter $exten | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $lwt} | foreach { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your extension filter back into child item and use *.* or *.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param 
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$source,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$destination,
    [string]$exten="*.*",
    [int]$olderthandays = 30
)
$lwt = (get-date).AddDays(-$olderthandays)

if(!(Test-Path $source)){
    Write-Output "Source directory does not exist."
    exit
}

if(!(Test-Path $destination)){
    Write-Output "Source directory does not exist."
    exit
}

if($olderthandays -lt 0){
    Write-Output "You can't provide a negative number of days. If you want everything deleted simply provide 0 for number of days."
    exit
}

if(!$exten.StartsWith('*.')){
    $exten = "*."+$exten
    $exten
}


try{
    Get-ChildItem $source -Filter $exten -ErrorAction Stop | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $lwt} | foreach {
        Write-Output $_.FullName 
       # Move-item $_.FullName $destination -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
catch{
    Write-Output "Something went wrong while moving items. Aborted operation."
}
```